# Match all nodes that contain the same label value, without knowing the value

Tags: neo4j

My nodes are all network hosts. One of the properties is ip address. I want to match all hosts with the same IP address.  Without having to enter any IP addresses

I tried the following code - to no avail. Goes on and eventually times out.
Approximately 25 000 nodes.

```
MATCH (n), (m)
WHERE ID(n) < ID(m) AND ANY(x IN n.ip WHERE x IN m.ip)
RETURN n, m;
```

Comment: do you want need a confirmation how correct is the Cypher syntax? please re-state your question so others can contribute accurately

Comment: Yes, confirmation whether or not the provided code snippet should resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want to group your nodes by common IP values? You just need a MATCH and a collect() for that:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n.ip as ipAddress, collect(n) as nodes
WHERE size(nodes) > 1
RETURN ipAddress, nodes
```

You could optionally add `ORDER BY size(nodes) DESC` if you want it ordered by the most nodes per ip address.

Comment: Brilliant, that worked. Is there any way to create relationships between the domain and IP addresses. Is that possible as they properties of the same node ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Relationships are between nodes, not properties. If you have :Domain nodes and :IPAddress nodes then yes you can create relationships between them. I think you need to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I understand. I was wandering if there was a way with my current dataset.  I realise I will have to make some changes to it. Essentially i have a csv file with hosted domains to IP addresses ( and some other data ). I wanted to illustrate the IP's with the most domains by showing the domains they host as relationships.

Comment: It does sound like you need nodes of two separate labels for this, and not a single node per row of the CSV, and then per row you can create the relationship between the two nodes you MERGEd in.

Comment: I tried the following: MATCH (n),(m)
WHERE n.domain = m.domain
CREATE (n)-[r:RESOLVES]->(m)
RETURN r,n.domain,m.ip